# using window function lag() to calculate percentage change

Tags: sql, postgresql, lag, window-functions, database-partitioning

I'm trying to calculate the difference between each row that each shares a specific attribute. For example, I have a week's worth of playtime of three games (RDR2, GTA5, Spyro) and I have calculated what percent of each day is spent on each game and I want to see what the percent change is day over day.

Hence, I wrote:

`percent - LAG(percent, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY game ORDER BY time DESC) AS games_delta`

but instead of getting the desired output of:

```
 |-------------------------------|
 | TIME    GAME   PERCENT  DELTA |
 |-------------------------------|
 | Dec 10  RDR2   25       15    |
 | Dec 10  GTA5   50       40    |
 | Dec 10  Spyro  25      -55    |
 | Dec 9   RDR2   10      -22    |
 | Dec 9   GTA5   10       10    |
 | Dec 9   Spyro  80       13    |
 | Dec 8   RDR2   33       ...
 | Dec 8   GTA5   0        ...
 | Dec 8   Spyro  67       ...
```

I get multiplicities of the games and totally wrong `game-delta`!:

```
 |-------------------------------|
 | TIME    GAME   PERCENT  DELTA |
 | Dec 10  RDR2   25       2     |
 | Dec 10  RDR2   25       4     |
 | Dec 10  RDR2   25      -4     |
 | Dec 10  RDR2   25       4     |
 | Dec 10  GTA5   10       5  ...
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

*Edit:*

```
SELECT  time,
        game,
        percent,
        games_delta
```

I also have the following in my `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`:

```
GROUP BY time, game, percent, games_delta
ORDER BY time DESC
```

*Edit 2:*

Here's my CTE:

```
cte_table4 (time, games_delta) AS
(
    SELECT time,
            percent - LAG(percent, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY game ORDER BY time DESC) AS games_delta

    FROM cte_table3
)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole SELECT? Are you sure you are only adding a single extra column. That cannot produce multiplicities.

Comment: Sure. I just added it. Thanks for the view!

Comment: Ah, you need to pre-compute the aggregation (`GROUP BY`) in a CTE (Common Table Expression). Then, you can use `LAG()` as a second step. Post the whole select, if you can and I can help. Using `LAG()` before grouping will result in these weird computations.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified the `SELECT` statement in my first edit was in the main body of my query. In my CTE I have nothing to `GROUP BY` or really any need for it I think?

Comment: @TheImpaler I also believe I precomputed the aggregation `GROUP BY` in the previous CTE `cte_table3` before I tried using `LAG()`

Comment: @TheImpaler I decided to compute the aggregation in the same CTE `cte_table4` as the `LAG()` and it worked! Thanks for the suggestion to move the `GROUP BY` into a CTE!

Comment: That's awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the aggregation `GROUP BY` in the *same* CTE as the `LAG()` will fix the issue